# Problem while saving user model into mongodb collection with Laravel

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, model, eloquent

I am using Laravel 5.7 with [jenssegers laravel-mongodb](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb). Here is my user model in `app/User.php`:

```
use \Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model as Moloquent;

class User extends Moloquent {
        public $username, $password, $firstName, $lastName, $emails, $mobiles, $remember_token;

        protected $fillable = [
            'username', 'password', 'firstName', 'lastName', 'emails', 'mobiles',
        ];

        protected $hidden = [
            'password', 'remember_token',
        ];

        protected $guarded = ['_id'];

}
```

when I create new db object using following code everything works well:

```
User::create(['username' => 'ehsankh', 'password' => Hash::make('secret'), 'firstName' => 'Ehsan', 'lastName' => 'Kh', 'emails' => array('a@b.c')]);
```

but consider the following:

```
$user = new User;
$user->username = 'ehsankh';
$user->password = Hash::make('secret');
$user->firstName = 'Ehsan';
$user->lastName = 'Kh';
$user->emails = ['a@b.com'];
$user->save();//using $user->create() also has the same result
```

this code only creates a document with 3 properties (_id, updated_at, created_at) in the users collection. I have no idea what can cause this problem. Any workaround would be appreciated.

Comment: Just a heads up, in your `create` code, there is no need to `->save()` after using `::create()`

Comment: Looking at the source code, it looks like using `create` sets the data to an array property named `attributes`, not directly to object properties?

Comment: @JonStirling when I use associated array and pass in into create method, everything is OK, but setting object properties does not work properly.

Comment: @EhsanKhodarahmi I know. My comment was a potential explanation as to why. It doesn't use them. Getting rid of `public $username, $password, $firstName, $lastName, $emails, $mobiles, $remember_token;` line would probably resolve, but I don't know what that would do to your code.

Comment: @JonStirling thanks for your note; Removing field definitions resolved the problem! Know php creates object fields dynamically and mongo driver saves them correctly!